# Linq Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, many-to-many

I have 3 tables in my db. AdminGroup, AdminSection and joining these two AdminAccess.
AdminGroup => AdminGroupId, AdminId
AdminSection => AdminSectionId, Code, Desc
AdminAccess => AdminSectionId, AdminGroupId

I need to get a list of all Codes available given AdminId.
This is what I have so far:

```
this.AdminGroupRepository.List().Where(x => x.Admin.Any(y => y.AdminId == loginEntity.AdminId))
```

But this gives me a list of AdminGroups and I simply need a List of Codes.

[image]

Comment: What's the relation of AdminSection and AdminGroup, also where is code? are you talking about code in AdminSection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it like so:

```
            var loginRoles =
                this.AdminSectionRepository.List().Where(
                    x => x.AdminGroup.Any(y => y.Admin.Any(q => q.AdminId == loginEntity.AdminId))).Select(
                        q => q.Code);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at Select to pull out individual properties or multiple properties into an anonymous object.

```
.Select(x => x.Code)
```

Comment: x.Code is not available. Or am i even selecting from the wrong repository. should it be SectionRepository? What would LinQ look like?